# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.servlet.ServletRequest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, pom.xml, parent-pom

I have the following pom. The build is successful.

When I run the project locally I get the below error. Any inputs on what I can change?

I tried to change the dependency version and all.

Do I have to change the dependency or any version or I have to instantiate?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/servlet/ServletRequest
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.servlet.ServletRequest
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
```

POM File - Do I need to instantiate jakarta?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.10</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>


    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <avro.version>1.8.2</avro.version>
        <apache.avro.version>1.8.2</apache.avro.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
        <log4j2.version>2.16.0</log4j2.version>
        <hadoop.version>3.2.3</hadoop.version>
        <jaxb-api.version>2.3.0</jaxb-api.version>
        <log4j.version>2.19.0</log4j.version>
        <spring-boot.version>2.7.10</spring-boot.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <!-- json to object and object to json begins -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- json to object and object to json ends -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL begins -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.31</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MySQL ends -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
            <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mock-server</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockserver-junit-jupiter-no-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>5.14.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                        <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams-test-utils</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- json to object and object to json begins -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- json to object and object to json ends -->

        <!-- splunk begins-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.splunk.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>splunk-library-javalogging</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- splunk ends-->

        <!-- jsypt begins -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--jsypt ends-->

        <!-- avro begins -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.avro.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <!-- avro ends -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-extensions-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- log4j 1 comaptibility ends-->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>

            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.5</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: In short, the problem is you. You are trying to outsmart the spring boot dependency management and to make matters worse include non compatible versions. Spring 6 isn't compatible with Spring Boot 2.x. Remove the `spring-web` dependency and remnove the exclude(s) from the starter you are currently doing.

Comment: I added spring-web separately to remove the security vulnerability

Comment: Which is incompatible, don't do things like that, the same for snakeyaml I don't think Spring Boot 2.7.10 works with snakeyaml. Which you probably also added to remove the security warning. Probably none of these apply as I doubt you are allowing YAML as input for your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to have all the dependencies set correctly is to generate pom.xml file using this page: https://start.spring.io/